# Wordpress Fetch data from separate website

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress

I have an html table in my wordpress page which displays "course dates and content".

```html
<table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<h3>Date</h3>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<h3>Area</h3>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<h3>Seats Available</h3>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Saturday, July 08, 2017</td>
<td>Johannesburg (Parktown) Microblading 2 Day Course</td>
<td>FULLY BOOKED</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Monday, July 10, 2017</td>
<td>Durban Microblading 2 Day Course</td>
<td>FULLY BOOKED</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Saturday, July 22, 2017</td>
<td>Cape Town Microblading 2 Day Course</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Monday, August 21, 2017</td>
<td>Durban Microblading 2 Day Course</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Saturday, August 26, 2017</td>
<td>Johannesburg (Parktown) Microblading 2 Day Course</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I would however like the content to update based on this link:
[Link to Content](http://www.eyelashextensions.co.za/inc_trainingschedule.asp?cno=7)

what would be the best method to "fetch" this data from the link and display it in my table? I did try an iFrame, but it did not product the desire result as the styling of the text etc did not match what is currently on the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can either re-create the content in your WP instance or you could fetch the page with cURL (depending on your hosting situation, it may be enabled for you). Mind you, you'll fetch the whole page (as a string of html) which you'll then have to trim the parts you need, reformat and insert into your page - not the easiest ... also, bear in mind that if the source changes (maybe they move the content to different URL or they relaunch the page with a new structure) you'll have to adjust on your side as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.eyelashextensions.co.za/inc_trainingschedule.asp?cno=7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$page = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($page);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$data = array(); // get all table rows and rows which are not headers
$table_rows = $xpath->query('//table[@id="tbl-all-product-view"]/tr[@class!="rowH"]');
foreach ($table_rows as $row => $tr) {
    foreach ($tr->childNodes as $td) {
        $data[$row][] = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', trim($td->nodeValue));
    }
    $data[$row] = array_values(array_filter($data[$row]));
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Where would I insert this?

Comment: @Pratik_Soni  - Would this be inserted into functions.php   ?

Comment: you can make saperate template and include required files and then place this code into it, then last step create one page from backend and assign this template to it so you can get the result in this page.